# View hierarchy incomplete after UIViewController viewDidLoad in iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios8.1

I created a subclass of a `UIViewController` and a storyboard view for this controller. In iOS 7 this works perfectly and loads without a problem. However, when testing in iOS 8.1 (on the simulator, as I don't have a 8.1 device available a.t.m.), the controller's view hierarchy is not completely loaded in `viewDidLoad`. As I understand the documentation, `viewDidLoad` is called once the entire hierarchy is loaded into memory.

My (simplified) hierarchy is as follows:

```
ViewController's view
 - unnamed UIView
   - unnamed UIView
     - UILabel with IBOutlet
 ...
```

In `viewDidLoad` I am trying to pin the label to its superview using PureLayout, however, this superview is nil causing an assertion failure.

I tried to log the view hierarchy by simply looping through the _view.subviews, their subviews, etc. The results were the following:

#### iOS 7

```
<UIView: 0x78634cc0; 
  - <UIView: 0x78634d50; 
     - <UIView: 0x78634de0; 
       - <UILabel: 0x78648d30; 
  ...
  - <_UILayoutGuide: 0x79ba5fa0; 
  - <_UILayoutGuide: 0x79b9b5e0;
```

#### iOS 8.1

```
<UIView: 0x7be2af30; 
 - <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7be2afd0; 
 - <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7be2b180;
```

What am I doing wrong? Can loading of certain views interfere with the `loadView` method? Or this normal behaviour? Perhaps this is something simulator specific?

### Edit

In my frustration I'm afraid I forgot to mention some things.

Firstly, I do not override the `loadView` method, but it is my understanding that `viewDidLoad` is called after `loadView` finished. So I suspected perhaps the `loadView` method returns prematurely.

Secondly, the views do eventually load in iOS 8, but simply not in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: If you use storyBoards forget loadView, loadView is in other to create a whole view by code.

Comment: If you are using a storyboard, you should not be overwriting `loadView`, as that's used to create views from code instead.

Comment: Probably your best option is to move part the code you have in viewDidLoad to awakeFromNib method or even to more secure (in order to know all views are ready) viewWillApperar

Comment: A suggestion: do all your Auto Layout constraint adding in `updateConstraints` or `updateViewConstraints`: https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks#where-to-add-constraints-in-code Why? It's the semantically correct place to make constraint changes, and is guaranteed to be called at the proper time in the layout cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the life-cycle of UI elements has changed from iOS7 to iOS8.
Your best option is to move the according code into viewWillAppear.

Comment: Is there anything official on this? I can't find anything. Also, I feel like Apple is messing up their own application design by forcing developers to set up their views outside of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find anything either. I always found the lack of documentation around UI life-cycle annoying, as it makes mixing lay-outing with storyboards and code a pain. Now it's even worse ...

Answer (score 0):

This is likely more of a comment, but I cannot comment so:

Make sure that in the storyboard all of your views are installed for the size class of device you are testing. You can check this property in the attribute inspector of each of your storyboard views.

If you are testing on a simulator device with a size class in which you do not have a view installed, that view and all of its subviews will not be added to the view hierarchy.

[image: Size Class Selection]